# Commits are extremely slow/hang after a few uploads

Tags: tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I've recently started to notice really annoying problems with VisualSVN(+server) and/or TortoiseSVN. The problem is occurring on multiple (2) machines. Both running Windows 7 x64

The VisualSVN-server is running Windows XP SP3.

What happens is that after say, 1 2 or 3 (or a bit more, but almost always at the same file) the commit just hangs on transferring data. With a speed of 0bytes/sec.

I can't find any error logs on the Server. I also just asked for a 45day trial of Enterprise Server for its logging capabilities but no errors there as well.

Accessing the repository disk itself is fast, I can search/copy/paste to that disk/SVN repo disk just fine.

The Visual SVN Server also does not use excessive amounts of memory nor CPU usage, which stays around 0-3%.
Both the Server as well as TortoiseSVN's memory footprint moves/changes which would indicate at least "something" is happening.

Committing with Eclipse (different project (PHP), different repository on the server) is going great. No slow downs, almost instant commits, with 1 file or 50files. The Eclipse plugin that I use is Subclipse.

I am currently quite stuck on this problem and it is prohibiting us from working with SVN right now.

[edit 2011-09-08 1557]
I've noticed that it goes extremely slow at 'large' files, for instance a 1700MB .resx (binary) or 77KB .h source (text) file. 'small' files > 10KB go almost instantly.

[edit 2011-09-08 1608]
I've just added the code to code.google.com to see if the problem is on my end or the server end. Adding to google code goes just fine, no hangs at all. 2,17MB transferred in 2mins and 37secs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found and fixed the problem. It appeared to have been a faulty NIC, speedtest.net resulted in ~1mbit, shoving in a different NIC pushed this to the max of 60mbit and solving my commit problems.